# how to upload image path into database in asp mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I new to MVC. I want to upload image path into the database. I refferd many tutorial. Most Of the tutorial says like

```
     [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            var allowedExtensions = new[] {  
            ".Jpg", ".png", ".jpg", "jpeg"  
        };
            tblDemo tbl = new tblDemo();
            tbl.Photo = file.ToString(); //getting complete url  
            tbl.Name = form["Name"];
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var ext = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            /..Remining code here../
}
```

but i am getting the error like Object reference not set to an instance of an object in file object (getting as file=NULL),I followed same like in many tutorial,all i am getting is same error. Then what is wrong with me?
Give me please some solution for uploading image path into database and image to the folder (i don't want to save image to the database)

Comment: Your source code doesn't say too much. Where's database insertion code? Where are you getting exception?

Comment: i am getting the error in tbl.Photo = file.ToString();

Comment: and the error is Object reference not set to an instance of an object. @Fka

Comment: I posted piece of my source code which is extremely simple. Are you sure file is uploaded?

Comment: Refer [uploading files with asp.net mvc](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/). And `tbl.Photo = file.ToString()` makes no sense. You need to save the file first and then assign the path.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke : Thanks sir... Now its working as i am expected

Answer (score 0):

I use following code to upload a file:

**model**

```
public class Model
{
    ...

    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

**controller**

```
public ActionResult SaveDetails(TargetGroupDetailModel model)
{
    if(model.File != null && model.File.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string fileName = model.File.FileName;
        ....
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Still my problem is not solved . The if condition is always false :( @Fka

Comment: Which means you don't even upload a file. Show me your View code, especially input with file.